# Html with python ( the loop give me just the first item and then it will exit

Tags: javascript, python, html

I need a little help with python and html. I have the following code :

```
<hr>

{% if Item is defined and item|length > 0 %}
<h3>items in the stack.</h3>
<table>
<TR>
<TH>define ID</TH>
<TH>date ID</TH>
<TH>Production ID</TH>
<TH>Status</TH>
<TH>strart ID</TH>
<TH>aarival ID</TH>
<TH>filename</TH>
<TH>Pices</TH>
</TR>
{% for i in item %}
<TR>
<TD>{{i.define ID}}</TD>
<TD>{{i.date ID}}</TD>
<TD>{{i.production_id}}</TD>
<TD>{{i.status}}</TD>
<TD>{{i.created_at}}</TD>
<TD>{{i.file_received_at}}</TD>
<TD>{{i.server_filename}}</TD>
<TD>{{i.count}}</TD>
</TR>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% else %}
<p class="quote">we can not find the item server  .</p>
{% endif %}

<hr>
```

The problem here is it only gives me the first item and then proceeds to exit the loop. I do not know why. Is there any one can help me in this?

Comment: Share your python code too

Comment: the python just take query form sql and convert it to dictionary